# Create COM component and ActiveX controls

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

Is is possible to create COM component and ActiveX controls in .Net (using c# language). I searched internet but i could`t get anything.
Thanks,
santhosh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare an interface and implement it with class.
If you have parameters/return values that are not OLE Automation compatible (custom structs, enums and so on), you might need to decorate them with the [MarshalAs attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx).
Add the [GUID attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx) to both.
Add the [COMVisible attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) to both. Alternatively, you can [mark the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182157(VS.80).aspx) with it.
Use [tlbexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c.aspx) to generate a type library for native clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, there is this article in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_object_in_c_.aspx). A friend of mine tried it and had some trouble accessing the COM-object from his unmanaged app, though, so there are some pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for information on the "COM Callable Wrapper".  Google for that, or a basic intro is here (I haven't read it): http://www.dnzone.com/ShowDetail.asp?NewsId=126

Answer (score 0):

the .Net and COM interoperability Handbook by Alan Gordon ISBN 0-13-046130-X is an essential resource if you're doing a lot of interop stuff

Comment: He's going the other way - accessing .NET via COM.