# Can MS Outlook add on call a .Net dll?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, add-on

Our customer needs some functionality added to Outlook. So they plan to create an add-on that calls some functionality we deliver. Probably this functionality will be implemented in a .Net assembly. Is it possible for an Outlook add-on to call some procedures in the .net assembly?
I am not sure how to implement Outlook add-ons, and have no idea which method they will choose implement it in, I just want to know however, if it is possible.

Thanks
Jeeji

Comment: can be done, e.g http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/MarkDeletedItemsRead.aspx

Comment: if you found your answer, toggle a check mark in left hand of correct answer to green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can program Outlook add-ons in .Net, so there is no reason they shouldn't be able to call your assembly from their code

**Update:** You can make a .Net assembly COM compatible. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186640/create-com-component-and-activex-controls-in-net-c-and-net-framework-3-5/186664#186664) outlines how you would go about it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I am not sure which technology they will use to program the Add-on. So I will need some standard way of giving them an interface which they can call. 
1- Can a .Net library be called, no matter which technology they use?
2- Is there any other standard way of specifying an interface, such as COM in the old days?
3- Is it a restriction that my assembly opens a modal dialog that returns a value to the caller depending on which choices the user made in the modal dialog?
Thanks a lot
Jeeji

Comment: @JihadHaddad: I've update my answer with details about making the assembly COM compatible