# create c# dll which can be used from both c# and c++

Tags: c#

I'm in the middle of moving my solution from c# to c++. I've created several native c++ dll and they just fine. It's easy to connect native dll to both c++ and c#. For c# i'm using P/Invoke for methods execution and `delegate` for callback, i just pass pointer to unmanaged memory and read it using [Marshall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.aspx) class.

Now I have opposite situation - I need to create `C#` project that NOW will be used from another `C#` project but LATER i will rewrite main project to C++ and so I need to access `C#` project from C++. It should offer just several methods: `PlaceOrder(void* pointerToStruct)` `CancelOrder(void* pointerToStruct)` and one call-back `delegate OrderUpdated(void* pointerToStruct)`

I'm looking for hints and examples. How can I create C# project which will be usable from both native C++ and C# and offer several methods + one callback.

In particular I don't now what should I do with memory - should I write to unmanaged memory at c# and read from it at c++ or should I write to managed memory at c# and read managed memory in c++ somehow... Pointer to structures which I pass at parameters should point to unmanaged memory or managed memory etc.

Comment: Hardly can you create dll export table (unless you do it in IL or managed C++); perhaps it is easier to create COM?

Comment: COM is slooooow and complicated and i'm writing low-latency software and it's just temporary solution so i would prefer something straightforward easy and fast.

Comment: i have c# part that i don't need to rewrite to c++. because i will throw it away once ported to linux. but until that I need to use c# from c++.

Comment: In general, a COM call is not slower than plain call to C a method in a dll (in this context), and not much more complicated than using a class. However, even if it were, I can't see how it is relevant for a temporary solution. Unless you can prove the significant difference, I would say that COM is the best way to go. arg/return value marshalling has to be done in both scenarios, and it might easily take majority of time need to execute a call.

Answer (score 3):

You may want on creation of COM component: [Create COM component and ActiveX controls in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186640/create-com-component-and-activex-controls-in-net-c-and-net-framework-3-5)

If you are developing in Windows8, you may think of creation Windows Component:

[Creating Windows Runtime Components in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with dll written on C# is that it's impossible to make export table (mark static methods as being exported): 
there's *DllImportAttribute* but there's no *DllExportAttribute* in C#. There're two by-ways though:

1. Write the dll (at least partially) on managed C++ that is specially designed for this purpose.
2. Change generated IL after C# source code compilation: 
    e.g. http://winch.pinkbile.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Dlltool
         http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37675/Simple-Method-of-DLL-Export-without-C-CLI

See also

[Is is possible to export functions from a C# DLL like in VS C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818850/is-is-possible-to-export-functions-from-a-c-sharp-dll-like-in-vs-c)

Comment: which of these options has better latency? what type of project should I create in VS, C# "Class Library"?

Comment: what about https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports ?

Comment: Both options have low latency, with changing IL being slightly better.

Comment: All we need is a small change in the generated IL, so many libraries could do it (Nuget is one of them).

Comment: regarding codeproject reference, i've found there "Resulting assembly will be 32-bit only.", doesn't work for me. will check if `dlltool` supports 64-bit. could you suggest something up-to-date which guarantees to work with VS2012 and 64-bit?